# Can't Download xls on Ajax Call of Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, excel

I want to download the .xls file generated at server and by the time .xls generate i want to lock the UI,but on Ajax call file is not getting downloaded
whereas data comes in browser but it did not show "save as" dialog box on browser

My problem Statements are,

1) I want to **download the .Xls** file generated at server on the **Ajax call** of 
   Jquery.

2) By the time .xls file getting generated,i want to **lock UI.**

**Jquery's** (**Ajax function, .ajaxform**) **not working** to download file.

**attr().submit()** function downloads the file successfully but it did not have the capability to notify completion of file download.

Note:1)'save as' option enabled from browser.

```
 2) .Xls file is getting generated from server side successfully
```

> **Please Provide if any alternative option available**

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to it do via ajax. You can do something like in your success callback.

```
window.location="download.xls/or/what/ever/?para1=value1...."
```

and set appropriate download headers on server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we can not download File from AJAX request

but you can do lock screen by belo code

```
$("#id_of_form input[type='submit']").click(function(e){

// your code for lock screen here

return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to keep track the download status(),U can easily lock your UI until the download is finish, We can do it with 2 ways,unfortunately by using ajax call we cant enable the download files,but if we use some additional html elements we can enable the downloading by jquery-ajax itself and u can lock your UI until jquery finishes the download.

Method 1

1. use your code behind to generate the xl(file)and save that file to any temp location
2. Call this method in ajax and in response send the name of that file which you saved before
3. create a temp `<a>` tag in jquery and enable the click event and it will download the file.
4. after finishing the download u can unlock your UI

   ```
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: AQ.AMT.Url + "/Home/StoreImage",
   //async: false,
   data: JSON.stringify({ request: request }),
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json", 
   success: function (Data) {

       var _tempPPT = AQ.AMT.Url + "/Download/Temp/" + Data.Result + ".pptx";
       // Trick for making downloadable link
       a = document.createElement('a');
       a.href = _tempPPT;// window.URL.createObjectURL(xhttp.response);
       a.id = "idanchrPPT";
       // Give filename you wish to download
       var today = new Date();
       var dd = today.getDate();
       var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
       var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
       if (dd < 10) {
           dd = '0' + dd
       }
       if (mm < 10) {
           mm = '0' + mm
       }
       today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
       if (flipName == "")
           a.download = "" + name + "-" + today + ".pptx";
       else
       a.download = "" + name + "-" + flipName + "-" + today + ".pptx";
       a.style.display = 'none';
       document.body.appendChild(a);
       a.click();
       $("#idanchrPPT").remove();


       //deleting the file
       var deleteFiles = {};
       deleteFiles.FilePath = Data.Result;
       setTimeout(function () {
           $.ajax({
               type: "Post",
               data: JSON.stringify({ deleteFiles: deleteFiles }),
               url: AQ.AMT.Url + "/Home/DeleteExportedPPt",
               async: true,
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (result) {
               },
               error: function (result) {
               }
           });
       }, 1000);
     },
     error: function (e) {
     }
   });
   ```

Method 2

Use XMLHttpRequest instead of Jquery $ajax

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var a;
    if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {

        var _tempPPT = AQ.AMT.Url + "/Download/Template/ExportPPtTrend1.pptx";

        // Trick for making downloadable link
        a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = _tempPPT;// window.URL.createObjectURL(xhttp.response);
        a.id = "idanchrPPT";
        var k = xhttp.responseText;
        // Give filename you wish to download
        a.download = "test-file.pptx";
        a.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(a);

        a.click();
        $("#idanchrPPT").remove();

        //alert("ok");
        $('.divLoader,.divBackgroundCo').hide();
    }
};
// Post data to URL which handles post request
xhttp.open("POST", urlToHandler);
//Send the proper header information along with the request
xhttp.responseType = 'text';
//xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


xhttp.send();
```